# Backup SQL DB without data in release pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, database-backups

How to take backup of SQL DB without data in release pipeline (Azure Devops/VSTS). And I have to store it on shared path. The DB is in on-premise server

**Update:**

After using the below command in "Command Line Scripts" task of release pipeline,

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /sourceconnectionstring:"Data
>   Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True"
>   /targetFile:E:\Test.dacpac /action:extract
>   /p:ExtractAllTableData=false /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true
>   /p:IgnorePermissions=true /p:Storage=Memory

I am getting the error as Login failed for user 'XXXXXX'. Below is the detailed log.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Backup SQL DB without data***

If what you want is only back up the definitions of the database objects and their related instance-level elements, which include like tables, stored procedures, views and users. Recommend you generate a [**DAC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) package file by calling `sqlpackage.exe`.

> A data-tier application (DAC) is a logical database management entity
>   that defines all of the SQL Server objects - like tables, views, and
>   instance objects, including logins - associated with a user's
>   database. A DAC is a self-contained unit of SQL Server database
>   deployment that enables data-tier developers and database
>   administrators to package SQL Server objects into a portable artifact
>   called a DAC package, also known as a DACPAC.

---

To generate a DAC package file, one is using **Extract Data-tier Application Wizard** but could not achieve in VSTS. Here you can use script in VSTS release pipeline to achieve this generated.

In release pipeline:

**(1)** First steps is apply below [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#help-for-the-extract-action) into `powershell`/`command` task:

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:extract /scs:"server=localhost;database=MerlinTbData;trusted_connection=true" /tf:"C:\SQL Server Management Studio\DAC Packages\AdventureWorks2012.dacpac"
```

equal with

```
sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:localhost /SourceDatabaseName:"MerlinTbData"  /TargetFile:"C:\SQL Server Management Studio\DAC Packages\MerlinTbData.dacpac"
```

In this script, it will save the DAC package file into local file system. But since what you want is let it store at a shared folder. So:

**(2)** The next step is using [Windows machine file copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task to copy this DAC package file to the shared folder.

Also, you can continue to use command script to achieve this copy.

---

**Update:**

Please use this below script which contain your username and password:

```
SqlPackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"*********"
 /SourceDatabaseName:"*****" /TargetFile:"*****" /SourceUser:"{SQLuser}" /SourcePassword:"{SQLPassword}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I run the command, I am getting the error as "Error extracting database:Could not connect to database server. Login failed for user '<Username>'.

Comment: @Kattesang, Wired. Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or private one? please use private agent to finish this extract. As I know, this command do not need username specified.

Comment: I am using custom agent pool. I have tried the same command in the server machine which is used as custom agent. There also I am facing the same error.

Comment: Even I have tried the command "sqlpackage /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:XXXXXX /SourceDatabaseName:XXXXX /TargetFile:"E:\XXXXXX.dacpac" in DB Server, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Kattesang, See my update script. I add the username and password specified into it.

Comment: When I run the command in DB server, I am getting the error as "Error extracting database:Could not save package to file. Access to the path 'E:\XXXXXX.dacpac' is denied". But as per my need, I have run the command in Custom Agent Pool server. Still I am getting the same old login failed error. I have tried with my windows credentials too. For that also, I am getting the same old login failed error. Please let me know still I am missing anything.

Comment: @Kattesang, this should be your system disk properties. You'd better change e disk's properties. Does your e disk has special permission. Please go its **security**,  add **everyone** and grant it full control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203319/discussion-between-kattesang-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Comment: But my need is to run it via pipeline. Still I am getting that login failed error.

Comment: @Kattesang. I find another type extract script from our backend. Please try with this in VSTS:  `SqlPackage.exe /sourceconnectionstring:"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog={DB name};Integrated Security=True" /targetFile:D:\DefaultCollection.dacpac /action:extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true /p:IgnorePermissions=true /p:Storage=Memory` This is the script we often applied in TFS DB extract. You can try with this.

Comment: I have tried both in release pipeline and directly in custom agent server. Bad luck for me. Still I am getting the same Login failed error.

Comment: @Kattesang, Would you mind share me your detailed log? These are the script we often used to migrate the TFS SQL database. Want to confirm if there anything disturb your succeed.  Also, you can see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=azure-devops

Comment: As the log is too long, I have updated the same in my original question. Please check it.

Comment: @Kattesang, Wow, really? The error you faced nearly make me crazy and almost doubtful of what I have learned from our team. So excited it worked now!! For the copy task, it also allow you input your local file path, see its definition https://imgur.com/a/EtOsBX2 Just specify your DAC file path here. Then copy it into your shared file path.

Comment: Additionally, please let me know how to use variables in command especially for password. I have tried the command as "sqlpackage.exe /TargetFile:"E:\Test_$(DateTime).dacpac" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"$(DBServerName)" /SourceDatabaseName:"$(DBName)" /SourceUser:"$(DBUser)" /SourcePassword:"$(DBPwd)". It is not working

Comment: @Kattesang, where do these variable store at? Variable tab or Variable group? Also, did you set them as secret?

Comment: Stored at Variable tab. For Source Password alone I have set as secret.

Comment: @Kattesang, I tried the similar variable format on my side. It's all work and the DAC was generated successfully: https://imgur.com/a/viNgZbG . Could you tell me what's the error message? Limited by comment words, I'd better suggest you raise a new ticket to solve this variable issue. Then I or other community member could share our suggestion to you.

Comment: @Kattesang, How the progress going now? Did you achieve the sql extract and put it in shared folder successfully now? If yes, appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.